# RHEL7でcertmongerが勝手に起動しようとしてエラーが出力されるのはなぜか

Tags: linux, systemd, rhel

RedHat Enterprise Linux 7 についてです。

certmonger.service を disable の状態のまま放置したところ、ひとりでにそのサービスが起動しようとしまして、以下のエラーが出力されました。

```
systemd: certmonger.service failed
```

何故、このメッセージが出たのか気になって投稿しました。

推測ですが、このサービスが「何かしらのトリガー」によって起動しようとされたけど、ステータスが disable になっているため、起動できなくてエラーとなったと考えています。

そこで、この certmonger.service が起動するような機能がOS標準に備わっているのか、何がトリガーになったと考えられるのかどなたかご教授頂けないでしょうか。

稚拙ながら予測をしますと、

・時間が経つと定期的に起動しようとするサービスなのか
　・直接関係しないコマンド実行？によって、起動しようとするサービスなのか
　・認証局や他サーバからのリクエスト通信によって、起動しようとするサービスなのか

のどれかなのかと思っています。

ざっくりとした質問で恐縮ですが、どうか宜しくお願いします。

Comment: systemdでのdisableはあくまで「システム(=OS)起動時のサービス起動を無効にする」という意味です。disableになっていようと、コマンドを実行するなりして手動で起動すること自体は可能です。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。disableについて誤解しておりました。。そうなりますと、「勝手に起動した原因」と「failedになった原因」それぞれが不明な状態なのと理解しました